# Bootstrap two inputs inline different widh

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Someone please help me to understand how to make my boostrap code for the inputs like in the image. I don't know how to make one input bigger and the other smaller. I tried input-smaller but doesn't work.

I want both inline inputs to have in total the same width like the firt input.

[image]

This is my code HTML + Bootstrap

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">N du registre de commerce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tva" placeholder="Saisissez votre numero RC">
 </div>
</div><!--form-group-->

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Personne autorisee a signer</label>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="yes3"  checked>Oui
     </label>
     <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="no3">Non
     </label> 
 </div>
</div><!--form-group-->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Rue / Numero</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street-nr" >
      </div> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div><!--form-group-->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Code postal / Ville</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip-code" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" >
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div><!--form-group-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have missed `<div class="row"></div>` Give it for each section and then give it a try.

UPDATE: I have added some more rows and columns in order to make the width same as the first. 
    
     
        N du registre de commerce

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Personne autorisee a signer</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="yes3"  checked>Oui
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="no3">Non
        </label>    
    </div>
</div></div><!--form-group-->

 <div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Rue / Numero</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" ></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="street-nr"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div></div><!--form-group-->

 <div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Code postal / Ville</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip-code" ></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" ></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div><!--form-group-->
```

Comment: I tried but now the two diff width inputs don't align anymore with the width of the first long input

Comment: @SorinDragomir I have edited my answer with the query. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @Smit. On the bootstrap page, on forms I saw only `<div class="form-group">` not any row for more input groups